# Retraction in aggregation with Databrick Delta

Tags: apache-flink, databricks, apache-kafka-streams, delta-lake, delta-live-tables

I have been working with kafka streams for a while, and been quite happy with it. Recently I deiced to explore the competition of the same "Kind", namely Flink and DataBrick Delta. I do not include Spark Structured Streaming standalone because it does not support on its own deletion/Retraction and what not.

While experimenting with DataBrick Delta, I have been trying to figure out how to implement retraction for aggregate, but could not figure out a way.

More specifically, In kafka streams, it is native, as we have in the Ktable api, the notion of adder and subtractor, when it comes to aggregation. When a value is deleted in the upstream Ktable, the subtractor is called downstream (KGroupTable)

Generally speaking, on value update, the old value is removed and the new one added to the aggregate.

I have been trying to figure out how to do that with dataBrick delta, but i could not.

How does one update aggregate and most importantly retract value from an aggregate, when working with Delta ? How does it work ?

I'm not expert in Flink but I found something similar to kafka streams that i seem to understand [emitUpdateWithRetract](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/dev/table/functions/udfs/#table-aggregate-functions)